What’s this account doing? [BOT]
Does anyone have insight on what this kind of strategy is and how it’s effective?
What I know for sure is they use Jito bundles for all or nothing transactions with an entry/exit that always returns profit.
They also only trade directly on Raydium AMM pools, no cross route arb.
Some pics below. I’m writing a bot myself and this strategy definitely caught my attention, I’m just trying to gain more knowledge about it.
Here’s the account: https://solscan.io/account/arsc4jbDnzaqcCLByyGo7fg7S2SmcFsWUzQuDtLZh2y#defiactivities
And here are a couple pictures from DexScreener



My understanding is this bot performs sandwich attacks using a dodgy/compromised RPC which allows him to see other people transactions just in time. That bot is everywhere and literally printing money by collecting a tax on everyone.
I had a look at some of the transactions, I believe the bot Jito bundles the victim's transaction with his own, also he uses one custom program..Pretty neat stuff. Hopefully that dodgy RPC will get caught soon..
